# PowerPoint VBA to open the Trim Audio dialog box

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I've created a sub that asks users for an audio file address, then imports it into the PowerPoint. Is there code that I can use to open the Trim Audio dialog box (Ribbon menu > Playback > Trim Audio) so that users can trim the audio file after it's been imported?

I know that you could use inputboxes to ask for the start and end point and then use `.Shape(AudioFileName).MediaFormat.StartPoint` and `.EndPoint`, but I'd prefer to open the Trim Audio dialog box because it allows users to listen to the audio.

I've searched the Microsoft help files, but unfortunately I can't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try

```vb
Sub OpenAudioTrimDialog()
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    ' Get the active slide
    Set sld = ActiveWindow.View.Slide
    If sld.Shapes.Count > 0 Then
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.Type = 16 Then ' msoMedia
                shp.Select
                ' open Trim Audio dialog
                Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "AudioToolsTrim"
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next shp
    End If
    MsgBox "No shape on slide"
End Sub
```

Please refers to Microsoft document.

> [CommandBars.ExecuteMso method (Office)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbars.executemso?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: Thanks! This works wonderfully. Do you know if there's a way to make the code wait until the user trims the audio before continuing the script? I have multiple audio files per slide, and want the trim audio dialog boxes to appear one at a time.

Comment: I don't know how to track the status of Trim Audio dialog.